# MongoDB won't update with testcafe tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mongoose, testcafe

Im using testcafe for GUI tests. I'm running the node server in the background and then start testing. When I'm navigating though the GUI with testcafe API it all works great, but when I'm trying to call a function that changes the db (hard coded in the test) the database isn't effected at all.
Here is my code:

```
fixture('Permissions')
.page('https://localhost');

test('go to permissions', async browser => {
    await onlineFormsController.createOnlineFrom("OMRI",'NEWFORM',async ()=>{
        await browser.click('#editUsersTree');
        await browser.click('#loadDefaultTree');
        await browser.wait(500);
        await browser.pressKey('enter');
        await browser.wait(500);
        await browser.pressKey('enter');
        await browser.click('#saveTree');
        await browser.pressKey('enter');
        await browser.navigateTo('https://localhost/Home');
        await browser.wait(5000);
    });

});
```

The function `onlineFormsController.createOnlineFrom` should create new form in my database, but nothing happened. It's working good separately form the `testcafe` test (tested it with `mocha` and it works great), but when I'm running the test with `testcafe` it's like this line is ignored or have no effects at all.

Any ideas what causing this problem?

Comment: maybe adding the content of this ```onlineFormsController.createOnlineFrom``` function/method would help in getting a better idea

Comment: also, can we maybe see the entire content of your fixture file? to see the imports section?

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe should not interfere with MongoDB work.

I recommend you the following:

- ensure that the `createOnlineFrom` returns a `Promise` object;
- do not pass function with test actions as a parameter. Since the `createOnlineFrom` returns a `Promise` object, you can organize your code in a more readable way:

```
    test('go to permissions', async browser => {
        await onlineFormsController.createOnlineFrom("OMRI",'NEWFORM');
        await browser.click('#editUsersTree');
    });
```

If these recommendations do not help, please provide the full code of your `createOnlineFrom` function.